# Uploading multiple large files and other form data in playframework 2/scala

Tags: scala, file-upload, playframework, playframework-2.0, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload multiple large files in the play framework using scala. I'm still a scala and play noob.

I got [some great code from here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/play-framework/dyolkIUU5t0/18HL2n7bdNIJ) which got me 90% of the way, but now I'm stuck again.

The main issue I have now is that I can only read the file data, not any other data that's been uploaded, and after poking around the play docs I'm unclear as to how to get at that from here. Any Suggestions appreciated!

```
  def directUpload(projectId: String) = Secured(parse.multipartFormData(myFilePartHandler)) { implicit request =>
    Ok("Done");
  }


def myFilePartHandler: BodyParsers.parse.Multipart.PartHandler[MultipartFormData.FilePart[Result]] = {
    parse.Multipart.handleFilePart {
      case parse.Multipart.FileInfo(partName, filename, contentType) =>
        println("Handling Streaming Upload:" + filename + "/" + partName + ", " + contentType);

        //Set up the PipedOutputStream here, give the input stream to a worker thread
        val pos: PipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
        val pis: PipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(pos);
        val worker: UploadFileWorker = new UploadFileWorker(pis,contentType.get);
        worker.start();

        //Read content to the POS
        play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee.fold[Array[Byte], PipedOutputStream](pos) { (os, data) =>
          os.write(data)
          os
        }.mapDone { os =>
          os.close()
          worker.join()
          if( worker.success )
            Ok("uplaod done. Size: " + worker.size )
          else
            Status(503)("Upload Failed");
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just curious. How large files are you being able to upload using this technique? Have you come across a limit to how big file you can upload?

Comment: @ChetanBhasin I'm afraid I wrote this a long time ago and am no longer using this code, so I have no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the data part. As you can guess (or look up in the documentation) the function to handle the data part ist called: `handleFilePart`.

```
def myFilePartHandler: BodyParsers.parse.Multipart.PartHandler[MultipartFormData.FilePart[Result]] = {
   parse.Multipart.handleFilePart {
     // ...
   }
   parse.Multipart.handleFilePart {
     // ...
   }
}
```

Another way would be the `handlePart` method. Check the documentation for more details.